# Add input in Angular bootstrap confirm module

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, popover, angular-bootstrap, uipopover

I am trying to use [Angular Bootstrap Confirm](https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-confirm) by Matt.

In his demo ([click here](http://mattlewis92.github.io/angular-bootstrap-confirm/)), it is mentioned that html can be used in the message. His code:

```
Are you really <b>sure</b> you want to do this?
```

I changed that to

```
Are you really <b>sure</b><br> you want to do this?
```

and it still worked. But if I try to add any complex element like input or button, it does not work.

```
Enter <b>Yes</b><br> <input type='text'> <br>and click 'Yes'
```

Is there a way to add input or textarea to the message?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to fork their code, based on the source, it is using a  class, so you could not do this through the interface.

https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-confirm/blob/master/src/angular-bootstrap-confirm.html